# can we call android native APIs

Tags: android

please tell me is their any native api for contact database??

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the contact db that you cant do with android api ?

Comment: Didn't get you question. Android already has a nice API to expose Contacts DB data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `ContactsContract` content provider (or the older `Contacts` content provider for Android 1.x).

Comment: actually i am new to android want to access contacts so that i can create apps which add or modify contacts data. can we will delete the contact???

Comment: @Neha: Yes you can inser/delete contacts. You can look into souce code of the **[ContactsManager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html)** application provided with the Android Samples.  _Also if you write comments then try to use **@** followed by the name of user, otherwise no one is notified of your comment._